# How to split a TreeList's children

Tags: java, treelist

I have been trying how to write a TreeList but failed so I googled one up and learn't from there. That works but what I am now trying to do and what I cannot find is how to split a TreeList. I have created 2 examples and both have failed me. The program just crashes. I am using Java and the TreeList class I am basing of is http://yet-another-tree-structure.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/src/com/tree/.

Original one

```
public TreeNode<T> removeAndCreate() {
    TreeNode<T> tn = new TreeNode<T>(data);
    tn.children = children;
    tn.elementsIndex = elementsIndex;
    elementsIndex.remove(this);
    children.remove(this);
    return tn;
}
```

The newer one I am using

```
public TreeNode<T> split() {
    TreeNode<T> tP = parent;
    while (tP.isRoot() == false) {
        tP = tP.parent;
    }
    TreeNode<T> tn = new TreeNode<T>(data);
    tn.children = children;
    tn.elementsIndex = elementsIndex;
    tP.elementsIndex.remove(this);
    tP.children.remove(this);
    return tn;
}
```

I thank you for the help I receive in advance.

Comment: What error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My answer relies on assumptions about what the OP wanted, but I agree with David that without knowing what you want `split` to actually do it is hard to know if it is working or not.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you got exactly what I wanted. Now I just got to see if it works.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok. I will give detailed information in future questions and give the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the classes you based things on and your second split I am going to assume that split means to take the node in question out of the current tree and return a new tree with node in question as its root. If that is what you are after then a few things need fixing. First of all your `split` function does:

```
TreeNode<T> tP = parent;
while (tP.isRoot() == false) {
    tP = tP.parent;
}
```

Problem is that if your current node (`this`) doesn't have a `parent` you will get a Null exception thrown (so try splitting the root node and you should get an error). I think you meant:

```
TreeNode<T> tP = this;
```

This change will avoid the loop accessing a `parent` that may be `null`. Next, you need to delete all the `elementsIndex` at each level from the `parent` and above. You then have to remove the `children` from your direct `parent` (if you have a `parent`).

I think the code you might be looking for is below (assuming I haven't missed something):

```
public TreeNode<T> split() {
    // Create a new root node for the tree we split off
    TreeNode<T> tn = new TreeNode<T>(data);
    tn.children = children;
    tn.elementsIndex = elementsIndex;

    // For each level of the tree above us make sure we remove
    // ourselves from the elementsIndex at EACH LEVEL until we
    // finish at the root.
    TreeNode<T> tP = this;
    while (tP.isRoot() == false) {
        tP = tP.parent;
        tP.elementsIndex.remove(this);
    }

    // If this node has a parent remove this node as one of
    // our parent's children. We aren't the child of any of the
    // levels above our parent
    if (parent != null)
        this.parent.children.remove(this);

    // Return the root of the newly split tree
    return tn;
}
```

Comment: Since I don't know the desired effect you were looking for one could do the split above without even creating the `tn` variable and simply return `this` from the `split` function.

Comment: It works very well and so far haven't found any bugs with it and it is fast